# Is this the proper way to insulate & vent shed style detached garage roof?

Tags: hvac, insulation, spray-foam, air-sealing

I have a detached garage which I am working on turning into a workshop. As part of the transformation, I would like to insulate it, finish the walls/ceiling and add a mini split for cooling and heating. Most of the time, the space will be unconditioned as I would only be running the HVAC when I am working on a project. I am located in PA, climate zone 5.

- The garage has a "shed style" single slope roof.
- I don't know the exact slope, but short side is 8ft, tall side is 12ft.
- It has no attic, just an open sloped ceiling following the roof line.
- The roof rafters are 2x8s.
- There are vented soffits across the entire length of the roof on both the top and bottom, but no ridge vent.

**My Plan**

- Install 1" spacers along the rafters at the corners  where the rafters meet roof sheathing.
- Attach 1" foam board to spacers, air sealing all joints with spray foam, creating a 1" channel across the entire width of every rafter bay to ventilate under roof sheathing.
- Add 1" foam board to seal between top plates and foam board in rafter bay (spray foam sealed around perimeter) - to completely air seal inside garage space from roof.
- Install 2x6 R23 Rockwool insulation to fill the rest of the rafter bay.

**My Questions/Concerns**

- Do I need a ridge vent for my type of roof? Despite the top vented soffit not being the highest point of the roof - it's only about 8 inches than the highest point. Is that sufficient to vent?
- Will 1" channels spanning each rafter bay be sufficient to vent the roof?

The roof:
[image: Roof]

The vented soffits:
[image: Vented Soffits]

Comment: 1" is sufficient. See [IRC R806.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.3). Avoid a Class I vapor barrier down low for your air sealing if you're using something beyond Kraft paper. It would create a moisture trap between the upper foam boards and the lower air seal. See Table R702.7(1) under [IRC R702.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-7-wall-covering#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch07_SecR702.7) for vapor barrier classes.

Comment: And your upper soffit vents are effectively a ridge vent. See [IRC R806.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.2) for vent area requirements. You definitely fall under the 1/300 category. You can find your climate zone by searching Chapter 11 of the IRC for your county's name (Philadelphia is 4A).

Comment: @popham I had planned on using rockwool insulation under the foam boards and a drop ceiling to finish it off.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have substantial venting at both top and bottom (or near them) this should work fine. No, you don't need additional ridge vent--enough scavenging should occur in that small section.

Yes, 1" should be adequate for such short runs. Most insulation baffles leave barely that after some flex anyway.